# accessing samba printer from Windows 11 client hangs forever

Tags: linux, windows, samba, printing

My samba server is running in standalone mode and sharing a CUPS printer. I can print from my android phones fine. Since updating to Windows 11, accessing the printer causes the application to hang, and I see continuous TCP connection attempts to port 135 (epmapper) on my samba host.

My samba host is Raspbian Bullseye with samba 2:4.13.13+dfsg-1~deb11u5. smbd is bound to TCP ports 139, 445. nmbd is bound to UDP ports 137, 138. Port 135 is not bound.

(I have tried installing the SMB1 client on my Windows 11 machine, because I am aware that SMB1 was not provided anymore, but that didn't change anything.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.